# Cronos cron Service Working Cron Job Demo net core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduled-tasks

I'm using the Cronos ServiceWorkerCronJobDemo ( https://github.com/dotnet-labs/ServiceWorkerCronJob )

In a Dot Net Core 5 application

As it stands it works as expected.
But as soon as I start to change the cron expression to what I need "0 0 1 * *" or @monthly
I need it to be schedule to run on the first of the month.

I get an invalid value for the interval error.

Does anyone have a solution?

[screen dump of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL19c.png)
[screen dump of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZZQR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression doesn't seem to find any problems, and I can parse it out with it.

[image]

Can you show the specific error and related code?

I have reviewed three articles, which may be helpful to you:

1.[Cronos](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos)

2.[Cron job troubleshooting guide](https://cronitor.io/cron-reference/cron-troubleshooting-guide)

3.[Schedule Cron Jobs using HostedService in ASP.NET Core](https://codeburst.io/schedule-cron-jobs-using-hostedservice-in-asp-net-core-e17c47ba06)

Comment: I have added some screen dumps in the original post.